# Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f07c325 -- permission denied for window type 2038

Tags: java, android, service

I want add floating icon but i received error as title.
I added permisson android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW  in manifest.
I hope to get help from comunication.

Error

/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dxlampro.floatingapp, PID: 7639
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f07c325 -- permission denied for window type 2038
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
....

### Bound Service

```
package com.unity3d.player;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.dxlampro.floatingapp.R;

public class FloatingMenu extends Service {
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public FloatingMenu getService() {
            return FloatingMenu.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"On Create Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"On Destroy Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public void startFloating(){
        View mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.floating_view, null);
        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LAYOUT_FLAG,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LAYOUT_FLAG,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);

    }
}
```

### MainActivity

```
package com.dxlampro.floatingapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.unity3d.player.FloatingMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FloatingMenu myService;
    private boolean isBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,FloatingMenu.class);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        // Phương thức này được hệ thống gọi khi kết nối tới service bị lỗi
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isBound = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            FloatingMenu.LocalBinder binder = (FloatingMenu.LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            myService.startFloating();
            isBound = true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isBound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From official docs(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW):  *If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission....* ... then there is how to ask and how to check ... I do not see this code here

Answer (score 2):

Add this in AndoridManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

and ask to grant the permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```